# Describe all possible groups of order 102, up to isomorphism. Without using semidirect product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I have a solution of this question using semidirect product. However I have no idea how to solve this without semidirect product. Would you help me?

Comment: Do you know about Sylow subgroups? Also try to use $102=2.3.17$.

Comment: Yes, I know. :D
I've tried. For example, I found $n_{17}=1$ so an 17-sylow group is normal in G. But, my question is not how to use Sylow, I know this, my question is how to describe all groups of order 102 (or pqr, p<q<r, primes) WITHOUT use semidirect product.

Comment: When you say "subgroups" do you mean "groups"? Otherwise, subgroups of what? Why aren't you allowed to use semidirect products?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean Groups. Because we didn't studied semidirect product yet. And I need to do this activity, whithout this, and make  a presentation about this. This is why I'm in trouble.

Comment: How are you going to describe them without using semidirect products? Are you going to write out the multiplication table of these groups when they aren't abelian? Good luck with that....